# Should I use recycler view for dynamic list with one item?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Well, I know that recycler view is used for lists changing at the runtime but my question is suppose my app is consisted of nested recycler views and I need a wrapper for the outmost RV which obviously has either one or zero items. Is it elegant to use a recycler view for that? if not what is the alternative?

Comment: If I understand you correct you have to use NestedScroolView for your "one" element. How could you event thought that RV with one/zero element would be elegant?:D

Comment: not sure if I  got it right, but if it's one element, it's not a list

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii there is a listener in the wrapper which is reliant on the nested rv. so it's can't work.

Comment: @λambduh If you do something in a weird way it's not mean that it can't work in a normal way. I don't know any details but things what you described is absolutely nonsens (no offence).

Answer (score 1):

yes you should use the recycler view if you know that item size in list may be increase or it may be with more item then you can use, also please check below link if your requirement view is match with this type

https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use recycler view to show data into list because app requirements can be changed any time so you should make your code always dynamic. Otherwise it will affect you later.